# How to know which ace editor fired an 'onchange' event?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, ace-editor

I have several active ACE editors on the same page, each of them is supposed to trigger an "on change" event.

```
editor[iGr].getSession().on('change', function(e) {
  // e contains the change type and data
 some_code...;
});
```

How do I know in the callback function which editor has triggered it ?
The traditional "e" object that is sent to the callback has just information on the data change itself but not on the editor itself.
And the "this" object is in my case not informative (an array of unnamed functions containing native code).

Comment: You are using an array of editors right. The index of the editor should help you to choose which editor based on your initialization.

Comment: Yes, but when I get to the 'onchange' function, the object that is received doesn't have any information about which editor fired it. For the moment, I do the requested action on all the editors, which is not very efficient. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Are you talking about the object event 'e' when the 'change' event is fired?

Comment: You can check your index 'iGr' which might help you in getting to know which editor?

Comment: Yes, "e" is the event object when the change event is fired. Actually, I found that I can use the context in which the callback function is written. This is elementary Javascript : if a variable is declared (i.e. the number of the editor), it will be seen in the callback function... hence I can recognise the editor.
Anyway, thanks for the discussion

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can answer the question myself : "e" is the event object when the change event is fired. I found that I can use the context in which the callback function is written. This is elementary Javascript : if a variable is declared (i.e. the number of the editor), it will be seen in the callback function...

Answer (score 0):

You can passed 2 arguments to handler function, the second is the editor instance.

```js
editor1.on("change", function(e, ins) {
    ins.setValue("HELLO on Editor 1", -1);
});

editor2.on("change", function(e, ins) {
    ins.setValue("HELLO on Editor 2", -1);
});
```